# dont share state between reusable component react native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Im creating a reusable Text component with a onFocus and onBlur animation, but when I put this in a form; the focus and blur event triggers the animation for every Input in the form... can you help me to avoid this behavior?

Here is the code if you need more details, but I think this is very clear

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text, Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const animatedPlaceholder = new Animated.Value(30);

class Input extends Component {

constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  id: '',
  isFocused: false,
  textLength: 0
 };
}

secureTextEntry = this.props.secureTextEntry || false;
autoCapitalize = this.props.autoCapitalize || 'sentences';
keyboardType = this.props.keyboardType || 'default';
focus = () => {
 this.setState({isFocused: true});
 Animated.timing(animatedPlaceholder, {
  toValue: 0,
  duration: 300
 }).start();
}

blur = () => {
 this.setState({isFocused: false});

  Animated.timing(animatedPlaceholder, {
    toValue: 30,
    duration: 300
  }).start();

}

render() {
 return(
  <View {...this.props}>
    <Animated.Text style={
      this.state.isFocused ? styles.usedValue : styles.emptyValue
    } > {this.props.placeholder} </Animated.Text>
    <TextInput
      onFocus={this.focus}
      onBlur={this.blur}
      autoCapitalize={this.autoCapitalize}
      secureTextEntry={this.secureTextEntry}
      keyboardType={this.keyboardType}
        style={
          styles.textInput
        }
      />
  </View>
);
}
}
```

```
export default Input;
```

Comment: what animation do you want, can you specitfy the nimation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite got your question, but i created a component which animates the place holder when its focused, animated back if value is empty,

check this snack example https://snack.expo.io/@ashwith00/frowning-cookie

Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text, Animated, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: '',
      isFocused: false,
      textLength: 0,
    };
    this.animatedPlaceholder = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  secureTextEntry = this.props.secureTextEntry || false;
  autoCapitalize = this.props.autoCapitalize || 'sentences';
  keyboardType = this.props.keyboardType || 'default';

  focus = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedPlaceholder, {
      toValue: -40,
      duration: 300,
    }).start();
  };

  blur = () => {
    if (!this.props.value) {
    Animated.timing(this.animatedPlaceholder, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 300,
    }).start();
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {value, onChangeText} = this.props;
    return (
      <View  style={[ {
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }]}>
        <Animated.Text
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: [{translateY: this.animatedPlaceholder}]
          }}>
          {' '}
          {this.props.placeholder}{' '}
        </Animated.Text>
        <TextInput
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
          onFocus={this.focus}
          onBlur={this.blur}
          autoCapitalize={this.autoCapitalize}
          secureTextEntry={this.secureTextEntry}
          keyboardType={this.keyboardType}
          style={styles.textInput}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  usedValue: {} ,
  emptyValue: {},
  textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 0.4
  }
})
```